# Создание анимации загрузки WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача: сделать крутящийся кружок, пока приложение будет делать свои дела. Для этой задачи пробовал использовать gif, но есть разные проблемы, после пробовал использовать font-awesome, но в итоге получаю лагающую иконку. Начал смотреть на англ форумах как это сделать в итоге наткнулся на тонны кода, который непонятно куда и как подключать (например вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359848/wpf-loading-spinner). Хотел бы узнать как создать простую иконку, которая будет плавно вращаться. Пример: в хроме во вкладке слева при загрузке страницы вертится такая.

Comment: Как вариант: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/blob/dev/README.md . сделай биндинг к Spin

Comment: Я бы если делал, то использовал бы именно идею font-awesome-wpf, которая предлагается в статье на которую вы ссылаетесь. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595927/2772330. Вроде там всё понятно: загружаешь nuget package, затем одна строчка: <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="4" />. Ну может быть еще где-нибудь надо будет прописать xmlns:fa или еще какую-нибудь мелочь. Видел такое решение на практике и без лагов, странно что у вас лагает.

Comment: @AndreyK. а почему могут возникать эти подтормаживания? Код выполняется в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Не знаю, говорю, что сходу пришло в голову: Думаю, что @Андрей уже показал, как надо делать. То же самое, наверное, можно сделать и с Font-Awesome (вместо Image - вращающийся TextBlock, в котором надпись шрифтом FA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возьмите любой элемент, который вы хотите вращать, я взял `Image`:

```
<Image Source="smile.png"
       Height="50" Width="50"/>
```

Мы будем анимировать его вращение, поэтому нужно добавить трансформацию вращения:

```
<Image Source="smile.png"
       Height="50" Width="50">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"
                         CenterX="25"
                         CenterY="25"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Дадим ей имя, чтобы удобно было обращаться и укажем центр вращения.

Теперь нужно запустить `DoubleAnimation` для свойства трансформации `Angle`, ну давайте сделаем это, например, на событие элемента `Loaded`, добавим соответствующий триггер:

```
<Image Source="smile.png"
       Height="50" Width="50">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"
                         CenterX="25"
                         CenterY="25"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotate"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                     By="360" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Готово!

[image: RotateSmile]

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. А как добиться максимальной плавности?

Comment: @Max, она будет плавной, с 60 fps вроде wpf выдает, просто гифка так записалась

Comment: Сейчас затестим)

Comment: А как запустить тригер `RoutedEvent = {Binding ...}` при щелчке на кнопку ?

Comment: @Сергей, `RoutedEvent="Click"` не работает?

Comment: @Андрей `Click` по изображению ?

Comment: @Сергей, пришлось запихать storyboard в ресурсы как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521363/6766879). Получилось такое решение: https://pastebin.com/Cu9DgVxJ

Comment: @Сергей, получилось?

Comment: @Андрей Нет, но я понял в чем дело. У меня висело событие Click на кнопке