# Анимация во время долгой загрузки

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение на WPF которое достаточно долго подключается к базе (получает и обрабатывает данные). Основываясь на ответе уважаемого @Андрея ([Создание анимации загрузки WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710886/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-wpf/711061?noredirect=1#comment1064258_711061)) На время загрузки сделал несложную анимацию.

Code-bechind :

```
    private void enterClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        Storyboard story = (Storyboard)this.Resources["storyboard"];
        story.Begin();
        .... загрузка...}
```

Ресурсы :

```
     <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotate"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
```

Изображение :

```
      <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/hourglass.png"
              Height="50" Width="50">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"
                                CenterX="25"
                                CenterY="25"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
```

Исключение `NullReferenceException` как побороть ?

Comment: Ну раз уж используете CodeBehind - запускайте анимацию оттуда

Comment: @Андрей запустил бы, если бы знал как )

Comment: @Андрей `this.BeginStoryboard(..?..);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж используете CodeBehind - запустите анимацию оттуда:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        By = 360,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    };
    rotate.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
}
```

Триггер и ресурсы уберите

Comment: А где у вас указывается Изображение ?

Comment: А где у вас `rotate`, не в `Image`, разве? :)

Comment: В `Image.RenderTransform`

Comment: Мы анимируем угол трансформации, а вот куда эта трансформация помещена - это не важно, поместите в Image - будет трансформироваться Image, поместите в кнопку - будет трансформироваться кнопка. Трансформироваться в данном случае - вращаться.

Comment: ок. вот мой xaml `<Image Source="hourglass.png" Height="50" x:Name="rotate"/>` code-bechind в точности как у вас в ответе - трансформации не происходит.

Comment: эээм, у вас в вопросе что написано, я использовал код оттуда. Удалите только триггер в кнопке, ну и ресурс `storyboard` не нужен больше, т.к. мы создаем тоже самое в коде

Comment: Просто при загрузке весь GUI станится может из за этого.

Comment: Блин, ну эта структура-то у вас осталась: <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/hourglass.png"
              Height="50" Width="50">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"
                                CenterX="25"
                                CenterY="25"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image> ?

Comment: rotate - это не Image, это RotateTransform

Comment: Дело в том что GUI станится. если я отключу загрузку то вращение идет но если включу загрузку то и вращения не происходит

Comment: @Сергей, ну так надо запускать в другом потоке загрузку

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо за помощь.