# Вращение вокруг центра изображения с помощью C# кода

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать вращение изображения, и хочу сделать это через C# код. Вот собственно он:

```
private async void LoadBarPart1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    do
    {
        if (img != null)
        {
            var RotateTransform = img.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            var transform = new RotateTransform(1 + (RotateTransform?.Angle ?? 0));
            img.RenderTransform = transform;
            await Task.Delay(3);
        }
    } while (***Условие выключения***);
}
```

Оно вращается, но есть одна беда, оно принимает за центр вращения левый верхний угол изображения, а как сделать так, что бы вращалось это все вокруг центра изображения?

Comment: Задайте [RenderTransformOrigin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) - Gets or sets the center point of any possible render transform declared by RenderTransform, relative to the bounds of the element.

Comment: @AK Помогло, спасибо. Оформи как ответ, мб кому-нить надо будет.

Comment: Либо укажите свойства CenterX и CenterY: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711061/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо задать [RenderTransformOrigin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) - центральную точку трансформации.

Центр изображения определяется так:

```
img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на нестандартное использование структуры Point -- это число от 0 до 1.

Ссылки по теме:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113846/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-change-rendertransformorigin-but-keep-location
- https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/03/08/772-use-rendertransformorigin-to-change-center-point-for-rotation-transforms/